# ¿Cualquier valor retornado detiene un ciclo?

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente código, el cual tengo un while que me repite N cantidad de productos comprados de una base de datos, en una td tengo un select que se llena con los productos totales en mi base de datos, seleccionando el que compre, el problema es que al mostrar el primer registro, se sale del ciclo y no me sigue mostrando los demás.

```
while ($RowProd = mssql_fetch_array($RProd)) {
        $options = &BuscarProds($RowProd['Modelo'],$RCab['Consignatario']);
        $c++;
        $trProd .= '<tr>
                    <td class="col-xs-1">
                        <input value="'.$c.'-'.$c2.'-'.$RCab['Consignatario'].'" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-xs-2">
                        <select class="form-control">'.$Mercancia.'</select>                        
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-xs-2">
                        <input value="'.$RowProd["Descripcion"].'" type="text" name="Descripcion[]" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-xs-1">
                        <input value="'.$RowProd["Cantidad"].'" id="cantidad" name="Cantidad[]" type="text" class="form-control">
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-xs-1">
                        <input value="'.$RowProd["Costo"].'" id="costo" name="Costo[]" type="text" class="form-control">
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-xs-1">
                        <input value="'.$RowProd["Total"].'" id="total" name="Total[]" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
                    </td>   
                </tr>';

    }
function &BuscarProds($code, $store)
    {
        static $Mercancia = '';
        $Tienda = CargarTienda($store); 
        $CSQPR = consultar2("SELECT CodProd, Descrip FROM SAPROD ORDER BY CodProd",0,$Tienda);
        while($rowT = mssql_fetch_array($CSQPR)){
            if($rowT['CodProd']==$code){
                $Mercancia .= '<option value="'.$code.'" selected>'.$code.'</option>';
            }else{
                $Mercancia .= '<option value="'.$rowT['CodProd'].'">'.$rowT['CodProd'].'</option>';    
            }
        }
        return $Mercancia;
    }
```

La cuestión es, tengo 47 Productos... pero en el while solo me muestra el primer registro, no sigue mostrando los demás... ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Por que llamas a la función por referencia `&BuscarProds()` intenta quitando `&` antes de la funcion.

Comment: Lo llame por un ejemplo que vi en php, pero con o sin eso, igual el `while` se sigue deteniendo en el primer registro.

Answer (score 0):

pues puedes revisar si `$RProd` realmente trae los 47 productos, haciendo un count o similar. 
lo mas probable es que un error en BuscarProds o CargarTienda esten deteniendo el script. Ahi necesitas activar errores de php, o usar un debugger.

Agregado: 
la funcion mssql_fech_array esta discontinuada en PHP 7. Te recomiendo usar PDO y ver si sigues con el mismo problema. 
También agregar deteccion de errores, al inicio del script agrega:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: Si, efectivamente al realizar el `count()` de la consulta me sale 47, meti un contador en el `while` y solo se incremente una sola vez, de manera que a la final de muestra (1-47) donde 1 es el contador dentro del `while` y 47 el `count` del resultado de la consulta

Comment: agregué mas informacion a la respuesta original